# SQL PIVOT Query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, union

i am trying to use group by in this query and have the result combined into 1 row instead of 5 and remove null values. what are the changes needs to be done?
result of the following code is the attached [image: output of following code]image 
[image: expected output- need this][image: output of source table p before pivot]

```
      select    datetime,dc_grp,disp,inst_id,oper,review,var,reqt_id, 
               [ITEM_NO],[MOLD_NO],[DEFECT],[DISPOSITION],[MISSING_PCS], 
               [DEPARTMENT] 
   FROM
   (
        SELECT TOP (10000) I.[dc_grp]
              ,I.[inst_id]
              ,I.[datetime]
              ,I.[serial]
              ,I.[oper]
              ,I.[review]
                 ,R.REQT_ID
                 ,reqt.reqt_name
                 ,R.DISP
                 ,R.VAR
                 ,R.ATTR
                 --,R.DATETIME       
          FROM [Data_Warehouse].[plant].[VW_IPC_INSTANCE] I
          ,[Data_Warehouse].[plant].[VW_IPC_DC_GRP] GRP
            ,[Data_Warehouse].[plant].[VW_IPC_RESULTS] R
                   ,[Data_Warehouse].[plant].[VW_IPC_Reqt] Reqt
          where
        i.dc_grp like '%MOLD INSPECTION%'
          AND I.DC_GRP = GRP.DC_GRP
          AND I.INST_ID = R.INST_ID
          and r.reqt_id = reqt.reqt_id
          and i.datetime = '2017-07-18 01:17:40.000'
        order by I.datetime desc
  ) p

  PIVOT 
 (
   max(ATTR) FOR reqt_name in 
 (  
     [ITEM_NO] ,[MOLD_NO] ,[DEFECT] ,
     [DISPOSITION],[MISSING_PCS],[DEPARTMENT]
 )
 ) as pvt
   order by datetime
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide input data and expected output? BTW: Please remove `reqt_id` from final query and check out the result.

Comment: i just edit the question so i want the output in 1 row insted of 5.if you understand by looking at the picture

Comment: Have you tried to remove `reqt_id` field? What's the result?

Comment: its the same. basically it removes that column and result stays the same

Comment: OK, from first select query and the second one too.

Comment: oh it worked. thank you so much

Comment: You're very welcome ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly to our discussion in comments to the question...

All what you need to do is to remove `reqt_id` field from both queries.